# Linux Command Line Find and Replace Hex

Tags: linux

Is there a command line Linux tool that will find and replace Hex representation of data in a binary file?  Example Usage?

For example: `'s/00FF00FFFF06500B49/11BB00BFFF06500B49/g'`

Comment: There's a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604964/binary-sed-replacement).

Comment: @Dennis Williamson, Agreed but those answers are more programmatic then an expected answer on ServerFault (i.e. several include non-sed/awk source code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl Scirpt:

```
my $find_packed = pack "H*", '0100000000000000FF0A16731485400000000000FFA10201FF22FFFFFFFF0200';
my $repl_packed = pack "H*", '0100000000000000FF0A16731485400010FFC545FFA10201FF22FFFFFFFF0200';
my $file = do { local $/; <> };
$file =~ s/\Q$find_packed/$repl_packed/g;
print $file;
```

Usage:

```
perl hexreplace.pl in_binary > out_binary
```

The above unpolished version seems to have worked for me, thanks to the guys in `#perl` on freenode :-)

Comment: I'm deleting my post about sed, it's not the right tool for this, sorry.